# Azure functions v3 /HTTP trigger functions : Limiting the request body and URL size

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, appsettings, azure-http-trigger

I would like to see how I can limit the **maxRequestLength** and **maxAllowedContentLength** properties in an API that was created using HTTP triggers with Azure functions v3 (using .Net core app 3.1)

I have tried using a **web.config** file that just got ignored (expected). But I'm not sure what other options can be done. Please note that I'm trying to decrease the default limits not increase them !

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this [blog](https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2015/12/09/troubleshooting-maxallowedcontentlength-exceeded/)

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP request length is limited to 100 MB (104,857,600 bytes), and the URL length is limited to 4 KB (4,096 bytes). These limits are specified by the httpRuntime element of the runtime's Web.config file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp

reference to web.config
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/v3.x/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/web.config

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. I was trying to find out how we can override those in my project.

Comment: not sure if this is handled by MS https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4993